# MS SQL2008 Nested Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

HI I'm trying to create a nested SQL Statment but cannot get it to work. The statement I want is to bring in the soonest due date from the purchaseorderitems table. where the quantityoutstanding >0. However I cannot get this to work. I want to return this field as EffectiveDate

```
SELECT  'Past Due Purchase Orders' AS TransactionType ,
        PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderId AS TransactionId ,
        ( SELECT TOP ( 1 )
                    DueDate
          FROM      PurchaseOrderItems
          WHERE     ( QuantityOutstanding > 0 )
          ORDER BY  DueDate
        ) AS EffectiveDate ,
        Suppliers.SupplierId ,
        Suppliers.Branch ,
        Suppliers.SupplierName ,
        Currencies.CurrencyDisplay ,
        CASE WHEN PurchaseOrderItems.ItemType = 'P'
             THEN Products.ProductId
             WHEN PurchaseOrderItems.ItemType = 'S' THEN Sundries.SundryId
             WHEN PurchaseOrderItems.ItemType = 'F'
             THEN FreightMethods.FreightMethodId
             ELSE PurchaseOrderItems.FreeTextItem
        END AS Item ,
        PurchaseOrderItems.ItemDescription ,
        PurchaseOrderItems.Quantity ,
        UnitsOfMeasureFactors.UnitOfMeasureFactorPrintText ,
        PurchaseOrderItems.CurItemValue AS TotalValue ,
        'PurchaseOrders' AS ScreenName ,
        CustomValues.CustomFieldValueBit AS AcknowledgementRx ,
        PurchaseOrders.DeliveryDateConfirmed ,
        CASE WHEN PurchaseOrders.DeliveryDateConfirmed = 0
                  AND CustomValues.CustomFieldValueBit = 0
             THEN 'Not Ack ¦ Not Conf'
             WHEN PurchaseOrders.DeliveryDateConfirmed = 1
                  AND CustomValues.CustomFieldValueBit = 0
             THEN 'Not Ack ¦ Conf'
             WHEN PurchaseOrders.DeliveryDateConfirmed = 0
                  AND CustomValues.CustomFieldValueBit = 1
             THEN 'Ack ¦ Not Conf'
             WHEN PurchaseOrders.DeliveryDateConfirmed = 1
                  AND CustomValues.CustomFieldValueBit = 1
             THEN 'Ack ¦ Conf'
        END AS Acktxt
FROM    PurchaseOrders
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PurchaseOrderItems ON PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrder = PurchaseOrderItems.PurchaseOrder
        INNER JOIN Suppliers ON PurchaseOrders.Supplier = Suppliers.Supplier
        INNER JOIN Currencies ON PurchaseOrders.Currency = Currencies.Currency
        INNER JOIN CustomValues ON PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrder = CustomValues.RecordNumber
        INNER JOIN CustomFields ON CustomValues.CustomField = CustomFields.CustomField
                                   AND CustomFields.CustomFieldId = 'Acknowledgement'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Products ON PurchaseOrderItems.Product = Products.Product
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Sundries ON PurchaseOrderItems.Sundry = Sundries.Sundry
        LEFT OUTER JOIN FreightMethods ON PurchaseOrderItems.FreightMethod = FreightMethods.FreightMethod
        LEFT OUTER JOIN UnitsOfMeasureFactors ON UnitsOfMeasureFactors.UnitOfMeasureFactor = PurchaseOrderItems.UnitOfMeasureFactor
WHERE   ( PurchaseOrders.SystemType = 'F' )
        AND ( PurchaseOrderItems.DueDate < GETDATE() )
        AND ( PurchaseOrderItems.QuantityOutstanding > 0 )
ORDER BY TransactionType ,
        Currencies.CurrencyDisplay ,
        EffectiveDate ,
        TransactionId
```

Comment: What is error message you get?

Comment: Hi Its not an error, the query brings in the same date for every record returned. I wanted the field effectivedate to be the soonest date from the purchaseorderitems table, for each purchaseorder.purchaseorderID

Comment: Then you need your subquery to reference table in outer statement, probably like this: `( SELECT TOP ( 1 )
                    DueDate
          FROM      PurchaseOrderItems
          WHERE     PurchaseOrderItems.PurchaseOrder = PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrder AND QuantityOutstanding > 0
          ORDER BY  DueDate
        ) AS EffectiveDate`

Comment: Perfect Thats Solved it!

Comment: Cool. Releasing as answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your subquery to reference table from the outer statement, like this:

```
( SELECT TOP 1
    DueDate
  FROM PurchaseOrderItems
  WHERE PurchaseOrderItems.PurchaseOrder = PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrder
    AND QuantityOutstanding > 0
  ORDER BY DueDate
) AS EffectiveDate
```